# php value is in the name of the array

Tags: php, jquery

I'm not the best to explain problems but i'll try my best.

So i'm developping a website with php and javascript and bootstrap.
I got a list of equipment that i want to be able to edit with a modal form.

What i'm doing is that i write the id of the equipment (from mysql) into the id of the picture that i'm supposed to click to edit the equipment.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtEAC.png)

When i'm clicking on it it goes to a JS page that execute an ajax request to get all the infos from the database.

Now the main problem: when i transfer the id with the ajax request (with $_POST) and i var_dump it to see if i really have it it shows like that: `Array ( [1] => )`
The number is actually the ID but i have no idea how to use it as a string to get my infos.

Comment: Change the way you send the post vars so it includes a meaningful name/key?

Comment: Please include the JS code you're using to set up your AJAX request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, your question is "**How can I fix the ajax request to process it in PHP?**"

Without seeing the specific code-part that you need help with, it's difficult to tell what exactly needs to be changed.

From your description, I assume that your Ajax request in JS looks like this

```js
// your code is either this:
jQuery.post( 'https://example.org?' + id );

// or this:
jQuery.post( 'https://example.org', id );
```

This will give you the URL `https://example.org?1`, which is equal to the URL `https://example.org?1=` (i.e., param "1" is an empty string)

You need to give the ID a param name. Like this:

```js
// This will work (add the string before the parameter value "id=")
jQuery.post( 'https://example.org?item=' + id );

// This is even better - set the post data as object:
jQuery.post( 'https://example.org', { 'item': id } );
```

In PHP you can then access the product id via `$_POST['item']`.
Of course, you can use any other param instead of "item" and even pass multiple values inside the post object.

---

**Update based on new comment**

The problem is, that you only pass the ID to the post-request, without assigning a name to it: `data: id`

Change this to `data: {item: id}` and you have `$_POST['item']` in PHP. Here's the full code:

```js
$.ajax({ 
    url: "getInfos.php", 
    type: "POST", 
    data: {item: id}, // <-- change this line!
    success:function(response){ 
        $('#bodyEdit').html(response); 
        $('#myModalEdit').modal('show'); 
    }, 
    error:function (resultat, statut, erreur){ 
        console.log(resultat, statut, erreur ); 
    } 
})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm actually using the ajax function in jquery `$.ajax({
            url: "getInfos.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: id,

            success:function(response){
                $('#bodyEdit').html(response);
                $('#myModalEdit').modal('show');
            },

            error:function (resultat, statut, erreur){

                console.log(resultat, statut, erreur );
            }
            
        });` So i'm not sure if i can add a variable in the link directly, but i will try to modificate the id before sending it

Comment: Great to hear it! You can "accept" this answer as the right one - Philipp would appreciate it, and it would help others who are having the same problem you did.

Comment: didn't see this comment until today, thx for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the answer above works better, it seems i've got more than one problem for this issue and the answer above helped me correct it for good

thanks to everyone that answers my question,
i found out about the problem.

First i was the ajax function built in jquery:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "getInfos.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {item: id}, // <-- change this line! credit to Philipp

            success:function(response){
                $('#bodyEdit').html(response);
                $('#myModalEdit').modal('show');
            },

            error:function (resultat, statut, erreur){

                console.log(resultat, statut, erreur );
            }

        });
```

I was sending the id with `data:` but the value was missing `.serialize` after it, wich adapt the value to the url query if i understood correctly.

working code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "getInfos.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: id.serialize(),

            success:function(response){
                $('#bodyEdit').html(response);
                $('#myModalEdit').modal('show');
            },

            error:function (resultat, statut, erreur){

                console.log(resultat, statut, erreur );
            }

        });
```

Comment: Future reference, you'd have gotten a slightly better answer if you'd mentioned jQuery in the original question and tags.

Comment: yeah i know didn't think of it when i posted, it's my first post too, i'll keep that in mind for the next time. thx for the info